# Changing csv data shape with python

Tags: python, csv

I have csv data file which I would like to manipulate. Would someone help me and let me know how I can change the format from

### | 61.00 | 62.00 | 31.00 | 32.00 |

### | 63.00 | 64.00 | 33.00 | 34.00 |

into the following with python pandas or numpy!

### 61.00 | 62.00 | 63.00 | 64.00 |

### 31.00 | 32.00 | 33.00 | 34.00 |

[csv table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7mWl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are there only 12 data fields ? Does your CSV has more rows or more column that needs to be taken into account ? Reshaping this can be done, but if you want to extend to more data you need to provide more information.

Comment: In CSV, I did not understand how many columns should you take from the first row and then move to the next row? In the example you read the first two columns [61, 62] and then you move to the second row [63, 64]. I prefer to enlarge your example to be enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this data. One way to do that is:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[61, 62, 31, 32],
              [63, 64, 33, 34]])

print(x.reshape(2,2,2).swapaxes(0,1).reshape(2,4))

#output
[[61 62 63 64]
 [31 32 33 34]]
```

Comment: Hi Phoenix, Thank you so much for your answer. I have a csv file with lots of quadruplex data like this. How I can reshape the entire csv file?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, did you find my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have big csv file with data organised in this way? How I can reshape the entire file? I upload a picture of the data!

Comment: I am currently using mobile as soon as I come back home. I will do it for you. You can understand my solution and start to generalize it :)